# How to display the ViewBag.products.Doc_Title and so on

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to MVC5,I had troubles with the `ViewBag`
I want to display the `ViewBag.products.Doc_Title`,`ViewBag.products.Doc_Content`,`ViewBag.products.Doc_Id` and so on
but i don't know how to do it
it display what i don't want
can anybody help me?

Here is my controller

```
public class DocProductController : Controller
{
    private IDocProductRepository repository;
    private IDocMainRepository repositoryMain;

    public DocProductController(IDocProductRepository docProductRepository, IDocMainRepository docMainRepository)
    {
        this.repository = docProductRepository;
        this.repositoryMain = docMainRepository;
    }


    public ActionResult List()
    {
        var products = from docProduct in repository.DocProduct
                       join docMain in repositoryMain.DocMain
                       on docProduct.Doc_Id equals docMain.Doc_Id
                       select new { DocMainTitle = docMain.Doc_Title, DocProductContent = docProduct.DocProduct_Content };

        ViewBag.products = products;


        //DocProductListView model = new DocProductListView
        //{
        //    DocProduct = repository.DocProduct
        //    .Join(repositoryMain.DocMain,
        //    docProduct => docProduct.Doc_Id,
        //    docMain => docMain.Doc_Id,
        //    (docProduct, docMain) => new { a = docMain.Doc_Id, b = docProduct.Doc_Id })
        //    .OrderByDescending(n => n.)
        //};    

        return View();
    }
}



//if my view is this

<div> 
    @foreach (dynamic p in ViewBag.products)
    {
        <div>
            @*<a href="D@(p.Doc_Id)">@p.Doc_Id</a>*@ 

            @p

        </div>
    }
</div>


//The page display:

{ DocMainTitle = name1, DocProductContent = content1 }
{ DocMainTitle = name2, DocProductContent = content2 }


//=====================================

//I want to display it like this
//@p.DocMainTitle    @p.DocProductContent 
//but it works error

<ul>
<li><h1>name1</h1>content1</li>
<li><h1>name2</h1>content2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're telling it to just display `p` so it is presumably calling its `ToString` method.  If you want to display parts of `p` in a specific format then call `String.Format` and provide the format and the parts.

Comment: I have 2 table, DocMain(Doc_Id,Doc_Title) ,DocProduct(Doc_Id,Doc_Content),I want to select the 2 table content by the same Doc_Id. And loop them. Display like:<ul> <li><a href="1">title1</a>content1</li> <li><a href="2">title2</a>content2</li><li><a href="3">title3</a>content3</li> </ul>....And how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply pass it to view like this:

```
return View(products);
```

and in your view define model of this type.

First you make a view model and strongly type you view with that model:

```
public class DocumentViewModel

{
 public int Doc_Id {get;set;}
 public string DocMainTitle { get; set;} 
 public string DocProductContent {get; set;} 
}
```

In your action do like this:

```
public ActionResult List()
    {
        var products = (from docProduct in repository.DocProduct
                       join docMain in repositoryMain.DocMain
                       on docProduct.Doc_Id equals docMain.Doc_Id
                       select new DocumentViewModel { DocMainTitle = docMain.Doc_Title, DocProductContent = docProduct.DocProduct_Content }).ToList<DocumentViewModel>(;

        ViewBag.products = products;



        return View(products );
    }
```

then in your view:

```
@model List<DocumentViewModel>


@foreach(var item in Model)
{
<h1>@item.DocMainTitle</h1>
<a>@item.Doc_Id</a>
}
```

**UPDATE**

IN your scenario, you want to pass multiple view models to a view, so you have to make another view model and create your two viewmodels as properties in it and pass this custom view model to view,

do like this:

```
public class CustomViewModel
{
 public DocumentViewModel  docViewModel {get;set;}
 public SceondViewModel sceond {get;set;}
}
```

and in action:

```
var products = (from docProduct in repository.DocProduct
                   join docMain in repositoryMain.DocMain
                   on docProduct.Doc_Id equals docMain.Doc_Id
                   select new DocumentViewModel { DocMainTitle = docMain.Doc_Title, DocProductContent = docProduct.DocProduct_Content }).ToList<DocumentViewModel>();




CustomViewModel custom = new CustomViewModel();



custom.docViewModel =products ;
custom.sceond  = secondviewmodel;

 return View(custom);
```

In view, you model will be:

```
@model CustomViewModel

@
{
var firstViewModel = Model.docViewModel;
var secondViewModel = Model.sceond;
}
```

Comment: I have made 2 domain model(Doc_Main,Doc_Product)  and 2 view model(Doc_MainListView,Doc_ProductListView).But I don't know how to do in controller and view.In the View,only can use a @model,how can i use Doc_MainListView,Doc_ProductListView together?

Comment: you need to make another viewmodel and add these two viewmodels inside it

Comment: i have updated answer for your scenario, hope it helps

Comment: I have 2 table, DocMain(Doc_Id,Doc_Title) ,DocProduct(Doc_Id,Doc_Content),I want to select the 2 table content by the same Doc_Id. And loop them. Display like:<ul>
<li><a href="1">title1</a>content1</li>
<li><a href="2">title2</a>content2</li><li><a href="3">title3</a>content3</li>
</ul>

Comment: for this case as well custom view model will do the job for you

Comment: you are getting the data in one query using joins right?

Comment: Yes,is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: the better way is to create a viewmodel and inside it make the model properties that you are returning

Comment: I have add another viewmodel,public class MainProductViewModel
    {
        public DocMainListView docMainListView { get; set; }
        public DocProductListView docProductListView { get; set; }
    }...But i don't know how to write action code for my scenario.

Comment: in action get the data for both and set properties of the MainProductViewModel as i told in answer

Comment: see the second last code part in which i am making viewmodel object and setting its properties, you will get data fromn db for both inner models and set mainviewmodel properties

Comment: the way i am getting doing in var products and assigning it to view model, you need to do the same way for both DocMainListView and DocProductLListView

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
    public class DocProductController : Controller
    {
        private IDocProductRepository repository;
        private IDocMainRepository repositoryMain;

        public DocProductController(IDocProductRepository docProductRepository,
              IDocMainRepository docMainRepository)
        {
            this.repository = docProductRepository;
            this.repositoryMain = docMainRepository;
        }


        public ActionResult DocProductList()
        {
            var model = new DocProductViewModel(repository);

                           //link tables(entities) part will be in the repository functions

                           //from docProduct in repository.DocProduct
                           //join docMain in repositoryMain.DocMain
                           //on docProduct.Doc_Id equals docMain.Doc_Id
                           //select new { DocMainTitle = docMain.Doc_Title,
                           //DocProductContent = docProduct.DocProduct_Content };


            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
public class DocProductViewModel
{
    private IDocProductRepository repository;
    public DocProductViewModel(IDocProductRepository docProductRepository)
        {
            this.repositoryMain = docMainRepository;
        }
    public IList<DocProduct> DocProductList
    {
        get
        {
           return repository.GetList();
        }
    }
}
```

Views in ~/views/DocProduct folder add view DocProductList.cshtml:

```
@model DocProductViewModel

<ul>
    @foreach(var v in model.DocProductList)
    {
        <li><h1>@v.Doc_Title</h1>@v.Doc_Id</li>
    }
</ul>
```